# SQL query to join table with XML element and get nested element properties

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, join

I have XML like below

```
<Parent>  
    <BOMLine> 
    **<partnumber>abc</partnumber>**
    <SortOrder>0</SortOrder> 
    <Component>
      <PartNo>SE3008</PartNo>
      <Comp>12P6383X012</Comp>
      <CompDesc>SQ Controller</CompDesc>
      <Qty>1</Qty>
    </Component>
    <ChangeOrder>
      <Qty>10</Qty>
      <COId>AS</COId>
      <IsQtyLinked>false</IsQtyLinked>
    </ChangeOrder> 
    <ChangeOrder>
      <Qty>10</Qty>
      <COId>AS1</COId>
      <IsQtyLinked>true</IsQtyLinked>
    </ChangeOrder>
  </BOMLine>
  <BOMLine> ....
</Parent>
```

and a temp table like this:

[image]

I want to join the xml and table on `PartNumber` properties and need the following output

[image]

And I don't want to use doc handle to handle xml,

Please help me to get the desired output.

I have tried following code, but I am confused how to get nested element from XML while joining.

```
DECLARE @TempTable TABLE (ID INT,
                          partnumber VARCHAR(200),
                          sortnumber INT)

INSERT INTO @TempTable (ID, partnumber, sortnumber) 
VALUES (123, 'abc', 1)



  DECLARE @xml XML ='<Parent>  
        <BOMLine> 
        <partnumber>abc</partnumber>
        <SortOrder>0</SortOrder> 
        <Component>
          <PartNo>SE3008</PartNo>
          <Comp>12P6383X012</Comp>
          <CompDesc>SQ Controller</CompDesc>
          <Qty>1</Qty>
        </Component>
        <ChangeOrder>
          <Qty>10</Qty>
          <COId>AS</COId>
          <IsQtyLinked>false</IsQtyLinked>
        </ChangeOrder> 
        <ChangeOrder>
          <Qty>10</Qty>
          <COId>AS1</COId>
          <IsQtyLinked>true</IsQtyLinked>
        </ChangeOrder>
      </BOMLine> 

     <BOMLine> 
        <partnumber>abc</partnumber>
        <SortOrder>0</SortOrder> 
        <Component>
          <PartNo>SE3008</PartNo>
          <Comp>12P6383X012</Comp>
          <CompDesc>SQ Controller</CompDesc>
          <Qty>1</Qty>
        </Component>
        <ChangeOrder>
          <Qty>10</Qty>
          <COId>AS</COId>
          <IsQtyLinked>false</IsQtyLinked>
        </ChangeOrder> 
        <ChangeOrder>
          <Qty>10</Qty>
          <COId>AS1</COId>
          <IsQtyLinked>true</IsQtyLinked>
        </ChangeOrder>
      </BOMLine> 
    </Parent> '




SELECT  TT.ID,
       TT.partnumber,
       B.CO.value('(Qty/text())[1]','int') AS Qty,
       B.CO.value('(COId/text())[1]','char(2)') AS COId,
       B.CO.value('(IsQtyLinked/text())[1]','varchar(5)') AS IsLinked
FROM @TempTable TT  
     CROSS APPLY @xml.nodes('Parent/BOMLine') P(BOM)
     CROSS APPLY P.BOM.nodes('./ChangeOrder') B(CO)
WHERE TT.partnumber = P.BOM.value('(partnumber/text())[1]','varchar(3)');
```

Comment: What have you tried so far, and why didn't it work? Where is the XML stored, in another table, a variable, *other*?

Comment: i tried but i am confuse how to get nested node properties, due to this i have posted this question

Comment: If you post your SQL then we can see where you went wrong. Without it, it's vrry difficult (impssible) for us to debug your code. Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/55968750/edit) your question with your attempt(s) so that we can help you. If you got any errors, post those too. Thanks.

Comment: please check code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You were close. This is the way I would do it with the sample data you've supplied:

```
SELECT TT.ID,
       TT.partnumber,
       B.CO.value('(Qty/text())[1]','int') AS Qty,
       B.CO.value('(COId/text())[1]','char(2)') AS COId,
       B.CO.value('(IsQtyLinked/text())[1]','varchar(5)') AS IsLinked
FROM @TempTable TT
     CROSS APPLY @xml.nodes('Parent/BOMLine') P(BOM)
     CROSS APPLY P.BOM.nodes('./ChangeOrder') B(CO)
WHERE TT.partnumber = P.BOM.value('(partnumber/text())[1]','varchar(3)');
```

Note I use `nodes` twice, once to get a row for each `BOMLine`, another for each `ChangeOrder`. I then use the `WHERE` to create an implicit `JOIN` to the table (`@TempTable`).

As this is sample data, note you may need to change the return data types from the XML to something more appropriate for your real data.

Comment: not working with multiple  <BOMLine>  tag under parent node

Comment: It will, @kushal, it uses `CROSS APPLY @xml.nodes('Parent/BOMLine') P(BOM)`; which generates a new rowset for every `BomLine` node under `Parent`. Your sample data only contains one `BOMLine` node though, so that's all I tested against. if you aren't getting multiple lines, that implies that something else is different; but i can't see your data so I have no way of knowing. you'll need to update your question if so.

Comment: I have updated XML please use above xml and execute query,

Comment: and insert 1 record into temp table ,  INSERT INTO @TempTable (ID, partnumber, sortnumber) 
VALUES (124, 'abc1', 1)

Comment: I get 4 rows there @kushal, which is as you expect: [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=bca60975e20688086df98837483501ce)

Comment: Query should like = **SELECT  TT.ID,
       TT.partnumber,
       B.CO.value('(Qty/text())[1]','int') AS Qty,
       B.CO.value('(COId/text())[1]','char(2)') AS COId,
       B.CO.value('(IsQtyLinked/text())[1]','varchar(5)') AS IsLinked
FROM @TempTable TT  
     inner JOIN @xml.nodes('Parent/BOMLine') P(BOM) 
     CROSS APPLY P.BOM.nodes('./ChangeOrder') B(CO) on TT.partnumber = P.BOM.value('(partnumber/text())[1]','varchar(30)') **

Comment: it is working now as expected with above query which is inserted in above comment